# Add a space between html link and logo

Tags: html, frontend

I am trying to add a space between the image logo and the link .
Not sure what to do .
I tried adding space in the text but didn't work  (>  FAA/ATC NEXT DAY PLAN)
I am backend guy but sometimes need to mess with front end :(

```
<tr> <td> <img src="images/page_white_acrobat_small.png" align="absbottom" /> <a style="font-size: 12px" href = ""onclick="Popup.open({url:'PERTI_Plan.pdf',width:800,height:500,resizable:'yes', separateWindow:true});">FAA/ATC NEXT DAY PLAN</a></td></tr>
```

[image]

Comment: Use &nbsp; instead of space

Comment: @yogendarji a margin would probably be a better, cleaner and more generalized solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately/fortunately, as you've now realized, multiple white space does not persist in the HTML layout.

CSS is your friend when it comes to formatting. You can add this rule to your stylesheet,

```
tr td img {
  margin-right: 1rem;
}
```

Otherwise, if you don't have a stylesheet, try adding an in-line style to your image tag as follows,

```
<tr> 
  <td> 
    <img src="images/page_white_acrobat_small.png" style="margin-right: 1rem;" align="absbottom" />
    <a style="font-size: 12px" href = ""onclick="Popup.open({url:PERTI_Plan.pdf',width:800,height:500,resizable:'yes', separateWindow:true});">FAA/ATC NEXT DAY PLAN</a>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Notice here that I have added `style="margin-right: 1rem"` to your  tag. This will apply this CSS rule directly to that tag, adding a margin on the right side with a size of 1 rem.

Comment: what is rem? ..and if I to shift the image a bit right

Comment: Great! See any online documentation for an explanation of what `rem` is. You can of course replace it with a percentage or px value.

Answer (score 1):

White space in your source code is truncated. Instead use a margin on the image or link.

E.g.

```
img {
  margin-right: 2em
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to give some margin here to give space between the image and link, you can give `margin-left` to `a`

```
td a{
  margin-left: 1px;
}
```

or `margin-right` to `img`

```
td img{
  margin-right: 1px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you have sevral way to do this :

the better solution is by css you can do :

```
td img{
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

but if you do this you will affect all the `td img` of your page.
in that case i advise you to put a class on your td to affect only this element and it's better if you have a list of this kind of file.

```
<tr class="fileMoreIcon"> 
<td> 
<img src="images/page_white_acrobat_small.png" align="absbottom" /> 
&nbsp;
<a ...........
```

and in css

```
.fileMoreIcon img{
   margin-right: 10px;
}
```

one other way is just to add a html space character `&nbsp;`

```
<tr> 
<td> 
<img src="images/page_white_acrobat_small.png" align="absbottom" /> 
&nbsp;
<a style="font-size: 12px" href = ""onclick="Popup.open({url:PERTI_Plan.pdf',width:800,height:500,resizable:'yes', separateWindow:true});">FAA/ATC NEXT DAY PLAN</a>
</td>
</tr>
```